# Having difficulty in understanding how $M\setminus (B \cap T) = (M\setminus B)\cup (M\setminus T)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand on an intuitive level why the above equality makes sense. Suppose that $M$ is the set of all students at a particular university who study mathematics. $B$ the set of all students studying Biology and $T$ the set of all students playing Tennis. Then:

$M\setminus (B \cap T)$ - the set of all mathematics students who do not both study mathematics and biology. This set does contain students who study math and biology or study math and play tennis. It just can't consist of mathematics students who do both.

$(M\setminus B)\cup (M\setminus T)$ - The set of mathematics students who do not study biology and\or who do not play Tennis.

Intuitively, it seems like the set on the left of the $=$ sign is larger than the one to the right because the set on the right excludes everyone with biology or tennis. The set to the left only excludes members if they are doing both activities, not if they only have one of them at a time.

Intuitively, how are these sets then the same?

Comment: Draw a Venn Diagram with circles M, B and T

Comment: It may be helpful to try to come up with a _concrete example_ of a student you think would be in one set but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall:

- $E\backslash F=E\cap F^c$.
- the D'Morgan laws : $(F\cap G)^c=F^c\cup G^c$ and $(F\cup G)^c=F^c\cap
   G^c$
- the distributive law: $E\cap ( F\cup G )=( E\cap F)\cup (E\cap G) $

Then
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
M\backslash (B\cap T) =& M\cap (B\cap T)^c& \mbox{By equality } E\backslash F=E\cap F^c \\[8pt]
            =& M\cap (B^c\cup T^c)        & \mbox{By D'Morgan law }\\[8pt]
            =& (M\cap B^c)\cup (M\cap T^c)& \mbox{By the distributive law}\\[8pt]
=& (M\backslash B)\cup (M\backslash T)& \mbox{By equality } E\backslash F=E\cap F^c \\[8pt]
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

"Intuitively, it seems like the set on the left of the == sign is larger than the one to the right because the set on the right excludes everyone with biology or tennis. The set to the left only excludes members if they are doing both activities, not if they only have one of them at a time."

What you have stated is true about the set on the left, but not the set on the right. $M\setminus B$ still includes students who play tennis but not biology, and $M\setminus T$ includes students who study biology but don't play tennis, so their union certainly is all students except for those who both study biology and play tennis.